# fixed div wrapper on bottom right with a circlecss animation and text centered inside

Tags: html, css

I have a circle animation with a centered text inside.
Everything is wrapped into a div.
I'm trying to put this wrapper div on the bottom right of the page.
Any tips about how to archive this without let centered text going outside the circle?

here the code example https://codepen.io/D_s/pen/oNzQdJy
thank you!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font: 3vw/3vw times;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 15vw);
  left: calc(50% - 15vw);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-text {
  font: 50px/50px times;
  letter-spacing: 22.5px;
  fill: white;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="10cm" height="10cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
<defs>
<path id="textPath" d="M 250 500 A 250,250 0 1 1 250 500.0001"/>
</defs>
<text class="circle-text" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#textPath" startOffset="50%" >SOLIDARITY  CHATBOT  </textPath></text>
</svg>
  <h1 class="centered">centered</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the code like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
}

.circle-text {
  font: 50px/50px times;
  letter-spacing: 22.5px;
  fill: white;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font: 3vw/3vw times;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="10cm" height="10cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
<defs>
<path id="textPath" d="M 250 500 A 250,250 0 1 1 250 500.0001"></path>
</defs>
<text class="circle-text" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#textPath" startOffset="50%">SOLIDARITY  CHATBOT  </textPath></text>
</svg>
  <h1 class="centered">centered</h1>
</div>
```